# Max[] is being inconsistent when applied to time series

Tags: curated-data, units, time-series

I am trying to create a list of annual maxima wind speeds. However the code I have come up with works inconsistently. i.e will produce a list for one weather station but will return `Max[Missing[NotAvailable],"the max wind speed"]` for another. And the error displayed is

> Max::nord2: Comparison of 44.45km/h and -[Infinity] is invalid.

I also can't just select the second value as this is part of an overall function that is meant to return a list of lists as such(I want a list of lists of 20 year maximas). Therefore I was wondering if there is a fix that won't affect the already working part.

I have also tried `DeleteCases`, `DeleteMissing` but as you can see the value I want is there. So any thoughts on how to extract it would be greatly appreciated!

Example of station that works:

```
x = (1996 + #) &;
y = (1997 + #) &;
years = {{x[#]}, {y[#]}} & /@ Range[20];

QuantityMagnitude[
  UnitConvert[
    Max[
      WindSpeedData[
        Entity["WeatherStation", "EGAA"]
      , Flatten[{#, "Day"}, 1]
      , UnitSystem -> "Metric"
      ]
    ]
  , "Meters/Seconds"
  ]
] & /@ years
```

> {12.45, 13.325, 11.6778, 11.6278, 11.6278, 12.1917, 9.00278, 10.5472, 
>   9.61944, 11.1111, 11.8833, 12.1417, 11.2139, 11.2667, 11.4722,
>   10.8556, 13.2222, 10.2361, 12.0389, 10.65}

A list of maxima.

Station that does not work:

```
x = (1996 + #) &;
y = (1997 + #) &;
years = {{x[#]}, {y[#]}} & /@ Range[20];
QuantityMagnitude[
  UnitConvert[
    Max[
      WindSpeedData[
        Entity["WeatherStation", "EGAE"]
      , Flatten[{#, "Day"}, 1]
      , UnitSystem -> "Metric"
      ]
    ]
  , "Meters/Seconds"
  ]
] & /@ years
```

> {13.4778, 14.4556, 16.6667, 13.375, QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[ Max[Missing["NotAvailable"], Quantity[44.45, ("Kilometers")/("Hours")]], "Meters/Seconds"]], 13.1694, 12.7056, 12.5, 14.25, 14.9194, 15.4333, 14.2, 13.2722, 12.7056, 17.3889, 14.6111, 15.8444, 13.7361,14.8167, 13.7361}

Comment: If you look at the time series for 2001 to 2002 then you will see Missing["NotAvailable"] for two entries. I suggest you drop those entries from the list and work with the remaining data. Are you happy to drop such entries?

Comment: I simply wanted to delete them. But have the "delete function" as part of the original line of code. As I said the functions I normally use i.e DeleteCases weren't working.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify what you want to do with the missing data in the `TimeSeries` as described [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/time-series/work-with-time-series-containing-missing-data.html).

For example, if you want to interpolate over `Missing`s:

```
x = (1996 + #) &;
y = (1997 + #) &;
years = {{x[#]}, {y[#]}} & /@ Range[20];
QuantityMagnitude[
  UnitConvert[
    Max[
      TimeSeries[ WindSpeedData[
        Entity["WeatherStation", "EGAE"]
      , Flatten[{#, "Day"}, 1]
      , UnitSystem -> "Metric"
      ],MissingDataMethod->"Interpolation"]
    ]
  , "Meters/Seconds"
  ]
] & /@ years

{13.4778, 14.4556, 16.6667, 13.375, 12.3472, 13.1694, 12.7056, 12.5, 14.25, 
14.9194, 15.4333, 14.2, 13.2722, 12.7056, 17.3889, 14.6111, 15.8444, 
13.7361, 14.8167, 13.7361}
```

Comment: It would be nice to also have some tutorial-style documentation for TimeSeries, e.g. something comparable to [the FEM tutorials](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html), which not only introduces functions, but also shows how they are meant to be used together and what is the usual workflow.